# Gradle build running for so long

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Within my android app, gradle build job taking so much time to get complete. By making single line change in code, taking around 2 hours to run the app and see the changes in app behavior. Following are the actual setup in my project:
Gradle version: 4.1.3
Gradle wrapper version: 6.5.1
Compile SDK: 30
Number of modules in app: 72

Any input or suggestions will be welcomed.

Comment: Gradle build time depends on your computer's performance, especially on the number of cores in the CPU and their frequency. To reduce the build time you may check for any [obfuscation tasks](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code). See whether your `build.gradle` has `minifyEnabled true` or `shrinkResources true`. If so make them `false`.

Comment: As you don't provide many details, I would recommend starting from this [official documentation page](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-analyzer), which covers the problem and possible resolutions quite well.